# Set a jQuery cookie to show popup only once

Tags: jquery, cookies, if-statement, popup

I'm an absolute newbie in jQuery. I'm learning, but there is a Christmas message that I need to get up and running within no time.

I've included these in the header of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.cookies.2.2.0.min.js"></script>`
```

Then follows the message using a jQuery popup. Here it is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
        var id = '#dialog';

        //Get the screen height and width
        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();

        //Set height and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
        $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

        //transition effect     
        $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);    
        $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.7);  

        //Get the window height and width
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();

        //Set the popup window to center
        $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
        $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2-220);

        //transition effect
        $(id).fadeIn(2000);     

    //if close button is clicked
    $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#mask').hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });     

    //if mask is clicked
    $('#mask').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });     

});

</script>
```

In the `body` I've put the message:

```
<div style="top: 199.5px; left: 200px; display: none;" id="dialog" class="window">  
XMAS MESSAGE
<a href="#" class="close">Shut this popup.</a>
</div>
```

So far so good. The next step would be not to bore my returning visitors with the same message over and over (postpone for sixty days would be good enough).

So I want to set a cookie using the jQuery cookie plug-in:

```
function setCookie() {
    $.cookie('test_status', '1', { path: '/', expires: 60 });
    return false;
}
```

Which is then found the next time a visitor hits the same page and the Christmas message is not shown till the message expires.

Now `if-else` statements are the higher kind of jQuery I'm not familiar with just yet. So, could anyone explain it to me?

Comment: When you fire your close events run the cookie function. Then at the top of your code do a check for the cookie value. If it exists don't show the modal.

Comment: jQuery is not a language, it doesn't have if else statements. It's just a bunch of javascript code. `if-else` statements in javascript are like [conditional statements in any programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_(programming)).

Answer (score 16):

Something of this kind might be of help:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if ($.cookie('test_status') != '1') {
    //show popup here
    $.cookie('test_status', '1', { expires: 60}); }
   });
```

Comment: Thanks for this, been wrestling with trying to get a cookie to work for ages.

Comment: jquery.cookie was renamed to js-cookie in a new repository: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie. The `$` (jquery dependency) was removed in the [version 2.0.0](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/releases/tag/v2.0.0)

Answer (score 3):

First include the jquery library.

After include the below script for cookies in jquery.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
```

Now put the below code into the footer :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       // initially popup is hidden:
        $('#stay-in-toch.popup-outer').hide();
        // Check for the "whenToShowDialog" cookie, if not found then show the dialog and save the cookie.
        // The cookie will expire and every 2 days and the dialog will show again.
        if ($.cookie('whenToShowDialog') == null) {
            // Create expiring cookie, 2 days from now:
            $.cookie('whenToShowDialog', 'yes', { expires: 2, path: '/' });

            // Show dialog
             $('#stay-in-toch.popup-outer').show();       
        }
    });
```

Comment: Great plugin, easy to use. The docs can be found here: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#readme

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    if ($.cookie('test_status')) {
        return;
    }

    //Rest of your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found this solution:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var cookie = document.cookie;
    if (cookie == "") {
        //show popup depending on url
        var url = window.location;
        if (url != "http://localhost/test/jquery-popup.html") {                                    
            setTimeout(function () {
                $.fn.colorbox({ html: '<div style="width:301px;height:194px;"><a href="http://livebook.in/"><img src="res/homer.jpg" style="width:301px;height:194px;" alt="The linked image" /></a></div>', open: true });
            }, 500);   
        }else {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $.fn.colorbox({html:'...', open:true});
            }, 500);
        }

        //set timeout for closing the popup
        setTimeout(function () { $.fn.colorbox.close(); }, 3000);

        //set cookie
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); //expire in 30 days
        var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
        document.cookie = "apparsoYES" + "=" + "YES" + "; " + expires;    
    }
});
```

this script creates a popup on page load, auto close it, creates a cookie so the popoup is showed only once time and can show different popups depending on the page

Comment: Take into account that `document.cookie` will return all cookies and not just your `apparsoYES` cookie

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is, when a new user visits your `Webpage`, you show a pop up, but as he surfs through other pages, the pop window should not come up.

Its very easy to achieve through `cookies`, check this code sample, this will help you

So i am including the code snippet used(you can also follow the below link for the same)

So, the script part is

```
var expDays = 1; // number of days the cookie should last

var page = "only-popup-once.html";
var windowprops = "width=300,height=200,location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes";

function GetCookie (name) {
var arg = name + "=";
var alen = arg.length;
var clen = document.cookie.length;
var i = 0;
while (i < clen) {
var j = i + alen;
if (document.cookie.substring(i, j) == arg)
return getCookieVal (j);
i = document.cookie.indexOf(" ", i) + 1;
if (i == 0) break;
}
return null;
}
function SetCookie (name, value) {
var argv = SetCookie.arguments;
var argc = SetCookie.arguments.length;
var expires = (argc > 2) ? argv[2] : null;
var path = (argc > 3) ? argv[3] : null;
var domain = (argc > 4) ? argv[4] : null;
var secure = (argc > 5) ? argv[5] : false;
document.cookie = name + "=" + escape (value) +
((expires == null) ? "" : ("; expires=" + expires.toGMTString())) +
((path == null) ? "" : ("; path=" + path)) +
((domain == null) ? "" : ("; domain=" + domain)) +
((secure == true) ? "; secure" : "");
}
function DeleteCookie (name) {
var exp = new Date();
exp.setTime (exp.getTime() - 1);
var cval = GetCookie (name);
document.cookie = name + "=" + cval + "; expires=" + exp.toGMTString();
}
var exp = new Date();
exp.setTime(exp.getTime() + (expDays*24*60*60*1000));
function amt(){
var count = GetCookie('count')
if(count == null) {
SetCookie('count','1')
return 1
}
else {
var newcount = parseInt(count) + 1;
DeleteCookie('count')
SetCookie('count',newcount,exp)
return count
   }
}
function getCookieVal(offset) {
var endstr = document.cookie.indexOf (";", offset);
if (endstr == -1)
endstr = document.cookie.length;
return unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, endstr));
}

function checkCount() {
var count = GetCookie('count');
if (count == null) {
count=1;
SetCookie('count', count, exp);

window.open(page, "", windowprops);

}
else {
count++;
SetCookie('count', count, exp);
   }
}
```

And following will be the body of DOM,

```
<BODY OnLoad="checkCount()">
```

http://www.jsmadeeasy.com/javascripts/Cookies/Only%20Popup%20Once/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

Using js-cookie
https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

And Magnific Popup 
http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

And inspired by the other answers I did this which I'm posting as it took me ages to work out so may help someone else. If anyone wants to edit and improve my code feel free.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function setCookie() {
    Cookies.set('test_status', '1', { expires: 1 })
    return false;
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){
   if (Cookies.get('test_status') != '1') {
         setTimeout(function(){
    $.magnificPopup.open({
     items: {
            src: '#message_popup' //ID OF INLINE ELEMENT
                },
            type:'inline',
      mainClass: 'mfp-zoom-out',
       closeBtnInside: true,
        fixedContentPos: true,
        removalDelay: 500,
            });
     }, 3000);  // equals 50 seconds
    Cookies.set('test_status', '1', { expires: 1}); }
   });
  //]]>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function closePopup() {
  $.magnificPopup.close();
}
</script>

//MY POP UP
<div id="message_popup" class="white-popup mfp-hide typography">
<button title="CLOSE" type="button" onClick="closePopup();">x</button>
  <div id="pop_inner">
   HELLO WORLD
  </div>
</div>
```