# Can't read jQuery cookies but can set them, "Uncaught TypeError: $.cookie is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, jquery-plugins

Got a strange thing happening. I'm working with jQuery with a Plugin/lib called JS Cookie.

**Got this in my HTML head:**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/js-cookie-master/src/js.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/cookiesetter.js"></script>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$( ".close" ).click(function() {
    Cookies.set('increase', '1', { expires: 7 });
    $( "#popup, #overlay" ).hide();
});

if ( $.cookie("increase")); {
        return;
    }

    alert('test');
});
```

**Output of the cookie:**

```
increase - 1
```

Ok, so that isn't broken.

But when I try to read a cookie with the following code:

```
    if ( $.cookie("increase")); {
        return;
    }

    alert('test');
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.cookie is not a function
```

What to do?

I searched Google, Stackoverflow etc. followed all the steps and checked the right loading order.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that JS cookie is the same as jQuery cookie? [The documentation](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) doesn't show use of the dollar symbol.

Comment: I'm surprised it works since your semi-colon is out of place on your `if` statement line

Comment: Yeah indeed, that was a bit silly. Need to debug that better :-)

Comment: @evolutionxbox As stated in the comment below, js-cookie is the same jquery.cookie, the difference is that the jquery dependency was removed in js-cookie v2, see here: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/releases/tag/v2.0.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$.cookie()` isn't a function of [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/?s=cookie) nor of [JS Cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie).

Instead use `Cookies.get('name')` to retrieve a cookie.

---

And as [Christopher Marshall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31705590/cant-read-jquery-cookies-but-can-set-them-uncaught-typeerror-cookie-is-not/31705673#comment51349616_31705590) said:

> I'm surprised it works since your semi-colon is out of place on your if statement

```
if ( $.cookie("increase")); {
                          ^----- remove
```

Comment: Thanks you very much! I'm silly I didn't saw that mistake. :-) I got this snippet: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8405718/1577471 but as stated, this one works!

Comment: That's because it's over 3 years old. Never rely just on snippets, instead go back to the actual plugin documentation. I think they stopped using the __$__ syntax a while ago.

Comment: Yeah, we remove jQuery dependency in the new project, see here: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/issues/349#issuecomment-116822133. The version 1.5.1 in the js-cookie project still uses jQuery in case you want to use the dollar sign, but I recommend dropping it and upgrading.

Comment: @evolutionxbox thanks for the explanation, really appreciate it!