# Display popup once per user/ visit on website using jQuery

Tags: jquery, cookies, popup

I am trying to make my popup appear once per-visit or per-user. It is a popup that asks you to subscribe. I would like for subscribed users to not receive the popup overtime they visit the website and also for users who visit the website(or specifically the homepage) more than once not to receive the popup as well. Ive tried using a cookie plug in but it is not working. I have provided my popup HTML and jQuery that I have been playing around with.

HTML:

```
  <br>
   {% form 'create_customer' %}


<center>
   <div id="emailf" class="clearfix large_form">
          <label for="email" class="label"></label>
          <input type="email" value="" name="customer[email]"placeholder="Email" id="email" class="text" style="text-align:center; margin: 0 auto; width:300px; height:30px;" />
        </div>
   <div id="password1" class="clearfix large_form">
          <label for="password" class="label"></label>
          <input type="password" value="" name="customer[password]"placeholder="Password" id="password" class="password text" style="text-align:center; margin: 0 auto; width:300px; height:30px;" />
        </div>



  <div id="btn1" class="clearfix large_form">
          <label for="Create" class="btn1"></label>
          <input type="submit" value="SIGN UP!" style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold;margin: 0 auto; width:310px; height:40px;background-color:#852B8A;color:white;" />
        </div>
  <div id="close">X</div>
 <!--  <input class="btn1" type="submit" value="Create" />-->
 <!-- <button id="shop"><a href="https://www.alzerina.com/collections/ready-to-wear">Sign Up Now!</a></button> -->

</center>
</div>   {% endform %}
```

jQuery:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (!$.cookie('alert')) {
      $('#popup_box').show();   
      var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); 
      $.cookie('alert', true, { expires: date });
    }
});

  </script>
```

Comment: FYI, `jquery.cookie.js` became [`js-cookie`](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) and the later should be used. That might not solve the problem, but still, it's better!

Comment: You can find the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405634/set-a-jquery-cookie-to-show-popup-only-once?rq=1

Comment: @Arun I have tried that solution and it is still not working